# How long does it take to renew a US passport?

Tags: usa, passports, us-citizens

For US citizens living in the United States, how long does it typically take (from start to finish) to renew a US passport? If the expedited fee is paid, how fast can it be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it depends on the issuing authority, but usually about two weeks if you pay the fee to have it expedited. You really can't ask for a definitive time, because it also depends on how busy they are. I have friends who paid the fee and got their passports renewed in just under two weeks, but that was a few years ago.

If you were born outside of the US and the issuing authority is the US State Department, it can take longer. I was informed of this when I received my daughter's passport, she was born abroad.

If you are out of the country and renewing through your local embassy, give it several months either way. I recently got a renewal in Manila which took just under 10 days, and inquired if that's the usual amount of time from most embassies and they said yes. But, don't let paperwork kerfuffles jeopardize your travel plans, or being abroad *without* a valid passport for a little while. Additionally, if renewing the passport for someone under the age of 16, *bring pictures of them* that show their growth from their last passport photo to their appearance *now*. The consulate might let you slide if the resemblance is uncanny, but be prepared - not having these could cause substantial delays.

To be safe, I'd allow at least two months. You might not be able to expedite it if you're out of the country, so keep that in mind. Otherwise, pay the extra fee, the worst that can happen is you get it sooner than expected.

That is of course if not having it renewed in time might put a dent in your travel plans.

Answer (score 4):

If you go to one of the processing centers it can be done in a few hours.  I used the one in [Chicago](http://travel.state.gov/passport/npic/agencies/agencies_905.html) it took about 3 hours.  If you are going to do it by mail I would give yourself at least 3 weeks.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr:** Official wait time is 4-6 weeks, but it's about 2 weeks during the off-season. No official statistics exist, but you could [call or email them](https://passportstatus.state.gov/) to ask, or just ask at your post office.

[According to The Bureau of Consular Affairs](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/News/passports/apply-early.html), 4-6 weeks or 2-3 weeks if expedited.

However, these time frames are not at all accurate, at least for off-peak months (roughly around Sep-Mar ?).

**Fri, Feb 1, 3pm**: I applied at a post office, was told that expediting is not really going to get me my passport any faster and to call if I hadn't got it within 2 weeks.

Wed, Feb 13, 5pm: Notified that my passport was printed and should arrive by Tue, Feb 19.

Wed, Feb 13, 8pm: Received tracking number indicating arrival by **Sat, Feb 16, 8pm**.

Sat, Feb 16: Arrived.

This was for a first-time passport so, if anything, renewals should be faster.

Comment: I sent in a renewal by mail last month - they received it Jan. 19 and I haven't received the new passport yet after 3+ weeks. The online status shows it's in processing. I did opt to get a passport card as well; I don't know if that has an impact on the overall time.

Comment: @ellinora: Very interesting. I also opted for a passport card, but that shouldn't affect processing time as they mail them separately.

Comment: Passport received 2/16, so that was about 4 weeks for a renewal with regular processing (priority mail delivery), even in off-season.