# Do I need a passport for a few days emergency visit to Canada?

Tags: passports, us-citizens, emergencies

My father had unexpected surgery and lives in Canada, Ontario. He is in icu on ventilator. If I need to go ASAP for a few days  do I need a passport? I have never had one. I would be leaving from Houston,Texas.

Answer (score 58):

I'm sorry to hear about your father. There are [a few different forms of travel documents that are acceptable for this trip](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/western-hemisphere-travel-initiative), but if you're traveling by air and don't have a passport, getting a passport is going to be necessary.

Assuming you're a US citizen, the State Department can get you a passport nearly immediately for an emergency like this. See [Get a Passport in a Hurry](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/hurry.html). You can [call them](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/emergencies.html) anytime to make an emergency appointment at the passport office in Houston, but you'll still need [the required documents](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/how-to-apply.html) for your application. You'll go to the office, hand everything over, pay the fee, and leave with a passport.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>If your father is in or near Toronto, and if you renewed your Texas drivers license recently and it is [RealID compliant](https://www.dps.texas.gov/DriverLicense/federalRealIdAct.htm) (it has a gold star on it), you’ll be able to fly from Texas to Buffalo, New York; then rent a car (make sure they know you’re going to Canada) or take the bus, train, or taxi to Toronto.</strike>

An EDL driver’s license is good at land crossings. You can’t take an international flight unfortunately.

Update: unfortunately it looks like while Texas has RealID driver licenses, they aren’t [Enhanced Drivers Licenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_driver%27s_license).